# Ember editable table cell

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Goal:**
I want to make an editable table cell component. If the user double clicks on the cell, it's content transforms to an input. If he/she click outside the input, or press enter, the cell returns to it's original state.

**What I have so far:**
I made a simple version, which is a good starting point. The component has an 'edit' state. If it false, the component shows the value. If true, the component shows an input box, and passes

- the value
- the component itself, as parent
- a function, which will be run on 'mouseLeave' event

http://jsbin.com/cugatedizu/1/edit

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: @blessenm the problem: now it changes back if the mouse leaves, but I want to change on a click outside the input box.

Comment: Change the `mouseLeave` event to `focusOut`

Comment: @blessenm I have already tried it, but it didn't work. also tried 'focus-out'.

Comment: @blessenm actually it works with focusOut, but first I have click on it. (to add focus). Not that good UX.:http://jsbin.com/cugatedizu/2/edit

Comment: http://jsbin.com/suwefa/1/edit Is this what you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77210/discussion-between-user3568719-and-blessenm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `focusOut` event and a observer.

Ur template will look like

```
{{#if edit}}
  {{input value=value focusOut=test parent=this}}
{{else}}
  {{value}}
{{/if}}
```

Add this observer to your component

```
setInputFocus: function() {
  if(this.get('edit')) { 
    Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
        this.$().find('input').focus();
    });
  }
}.observes('edit')
```

**[Working demo.](http://jsbin.com/suwefa/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 0):

A more flexible way to write this would be:

```
{{input value=value parent=this}}  //(removed mouseLeave=test)
```

Then in your component.js you can do:

```
test: function(){
    console.log('mouse out');
    this.get('parent').set('edit', false);

}.on('focusOut', 'mouseLeave')
```

In this way you can be more flexible in how you handle events. In the code above, the cell becomes uneditable if the user hits the tab key, and the mouseLeave behaviour is preserved.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/logihuxeki/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This editable table widget may work for you too, although it transforms the entire table: http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/